# How do I save my keras model into google drive or the computer?

Tags: python, keras, google-drive-api, save, google-colaboratory

No code for this,
I am making a presentable ML project, and I want to import my keras model into google drive or save it in my computer so I can use the "model.predict()" function in an instant.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use model.save() and model.load()

More details and examples [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize)

If you are using google colab, you can mount you google drive in the notebook (menu in the left) and save and load directly from drive.

Comment: I kinda know that already.

Comment: And those methods don't solve your problem? can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: well, training a model takes forever so I wanted to save a model so I can predict without delay.

Comment: But that is exactly what model.save does, when you save the model with model.save the weights are included, you don't need to train it again. Just use model = keras.models.load_model('path') then model.predict(input). Just make sure to use .h5 format

Answer (score 0):

On Kaggle: I think all you need is to go to the right hand side of the notebook.  under Notebook options (Persistence) click Variables and files, that saves your file.
Note: model.save(....keras) should have ran already on your notebook